# Regex match the start of a word but replace the whole word

Tags: c#

I want to search for all words that start with a pattern and then replace the whole word with another text.
I see that we can do a whole word match only and replace it but did not find a way of matching the start and replacing the whole word.

```
string input = "My name is ABCDEFG and not ABCDQWER"
string pattern = @"\bABCD";
string replace = "text";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Above code obviously won't work for me because we are replacing only the text that matched.
If I run the code on the above text, I get "My name is textEFG and not textQWER".
What I need is "My name is text and not text". The only way I see if doing a loop on all the words but trying to avoid that and see if we have a regex way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try matching on the pattern `\bABCD\w*`, which would match any word which *starts* with `ABCD`, which however may be longer than that.

```cs
string input = "My name is ABCDEFG and not ABCDQWER";
string pattern = @"\bABCD\w*";
string replace = "text";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
Console.WriteLine(result);  // My name is text and not text
```